# [Oracle]: A query hangs when is executed in a partition but not in others partitions for the same table

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, indexing, partitioning

I have a partitioned table by column A. The table for the partition Z has 800000 records, and for the partition V has 5000000 (many more). I've checked all the indexes and are ACTIVE.

The pàrtitions in the table ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS look okay.

**I execute a query in the partition Z and it hangs and I had to kill it when it was executing for 5 hours but instead in the partition V goes really fast, 1,2 seconds.**

I've also observed that the same query in different partition uses different indexes of the table.

I have no clue why.

Does anyone have any idea why this may happen?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: check the execution plan of your query for both partitions.

Comment: Did you look at your execution plan? Have you recently run statistics on the  table?

Comment: Yes, the execution plan shows a cost of 11258, cardinality 1 and bytes 315 for the query in the partition V and a cost of 3, cardinality 1 and 2368 bytes in the partition Z. and statistics have been run on the table recently. May it be for the statistics?

Comment: @JaviHernandez There are a lot of details in an execution plan, and a lot of ways the plans can go wrong.  It would help to run `explain plan for select ...;` and then `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);` and include the entire result in the question.

Comment: @BrianLeach excuse me, may I ask you a question? Is it necessary to update the indexes from a partition after running statistics on a table?

Comment: @JaviHernandez It is not necessary at all to update indexes after running statistics, in fact updating the indexes will invalidate your current statistics, which is why the 'COMPUTE STATISTICS' clause is on the alter index command. Remember, an index is a structure on disk pointing to rows within a table. Statistics are a DB analysis of the table and its indexes to allow the cost based optimizer to make good decisions regarding query optimization. Rebuilding indexes is usually only necessary when there have been many changes to the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the replies, I know I didn't give much information.

The problem is solved by rebuilding all the indexes for the partition Z.

Apparently the problem was caused by the statistics and I had to rebuild the indexes.

The indexes were rebuilt this way:

```
alter index TABLE_IDX0 rebuild partition Z  ONLINE COMPUTE STATISTICS;
alter index TABLE_IDX1 rebuild partition Z  ONLINE COMPUTE STATISTICS;
alter index TABLE_IDX2 rebuild partition Z  ONLINE COMPUTE STATISTICS;
alter index TABLE_IDX3 rebuild partition Z  ONLINE COMPUTE STATISTICS;
alter index TABLE_IDX4 rebuild partition Z  ONLINE COMPUTE STATISTICS;
alter index TABLE_IDX5 rebuild partition Z  ONLINE COMPUTE STATISTICS;
```